# Redimencionar un QTabWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Desde un QMainWindow llamo un QTabWidget para que este actue como subWindow en un mdiArea, todo bien lo único que aparece muy pequeño, he intentado darle un tamaño con la función setGeometry desde el main y desde el propio tabwidget pero siempre aparece pequeño.

Así es como defino el QTabWidget, las 2 últimas funciones son para poner los componentes dentro de los tabs

```py
class Index(QTabWidget):
    x = 500
    y = 400

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Laboratorio 1")

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)

        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        self.addTab(self.tab, "Ejercicio 1")
        self.addTab(self.tab2, "Ejercicio 2")

        self.exercise01()
        self.exercise02()
```

Y así es como lo llamo desde el QMainWindow:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMenu, QMenuBar, QDialog, QPushButton, QLabel, QAction, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

from lab01.index import Index as lab01exe01

class MainPyQt(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.resize(800,600)
        self.setWindowTitle("LABORATORIOS PYTHON")
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Mensaje de bienvenida')

        self.mdiArea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea(self)
        self.mdiArea.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 600)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdiArea)

        self.initMenuBar()

    def initMenuBar(self):
        menuBar = self.menuBar()

        menuLab01 = menuBar.addMenu("Laboratorio I")

        actLab01Exe01 = QAction(QIcon(), "Ejercicio 1", self)
        #actLab01Exe01.setShortcut("Ctrl+o")
        actLab01Exe01.setStatusTip("Abrir ejercicio 1")
        actLab01Exe01.triggered.connect(self.openLab01Exe01)
        menuLab01.addAction(actLab01Exe01)

    def openLab01Exe01(self):
        subwin = lab01exe01(self)
        subwin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 500, 500))
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(subwin)
        #subwin.setGeometry(20, 50, subwin.x, subwin.y)
        subwin.show()
```

Siempre aparece así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la clase que hereda del QTabWidget se llama `Index` pero no veo que lo uses cuando añades el widget al QMdiArea, si deseas ayuda provee un [MRE]

Comment: @eyllanesc sí lo hace, solo que me olvidé poner que lo importo llamandolo de otra manera, ya lo agregué

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tamaño de la ventana que se muestra es determinado por el tamaño del QMdiSubWindow, pero segun el nombre de las variables asumo que piensas `subwin` es un QMdiSubWindow pero no lo es. Asi que la solución es obtener el QMdiSubWindow que retorna el método `addSubWindow()` y establecer la geometria a ese elemento:

```py
def openLab01Exe01(self):
    w = lab01exe01(self)
    subwin = self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(w)
    subwin.setGeometry(20, 50, 500, 400)
    subwin.show()
```